# Unable to use tags in swagger documentation

Tags: ruby, swagger, grape-api, openapi

I had my API looking great in Swagger like this:

```
desc 'blah', tags: ['User Management']
```

All my API calls were well grouped with the 'tags'. However, I needed to change the 'desc' line to include a necessary header paramater:

```
desc 'blah' do
  headers Authorization {
    ...
  }
```

If I pass 'tags' to 'desc' like I was before it is ignored and I get a deprecated warning. Now my APIs are no longer logically grouped like they were before - I can't find a way to continue to group my API calls in Swagger. Anyone know a workaround?
I'm using Ruby w/ the Grape framework (no rails).